# FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) - Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, artificial-intelligence, decode, openai-api

My code produces a response like this (I use the OpenAI API):

```
Tut mir leid, ein Fehler ist aufgetreten. Details: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
Im Englischen stellt man sich normalerweise auf die folgende Weise vor:
^
```

`Tut mir leid, ein Fehler ist aufgetreten` means `Sorry, an error has occurred`

Why is this so? "at character" and the number is random...

```
  Future<String> _fetchApiKey() async {
    final DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('keys')
            .doc('openapi')
            .get();

    final apiKey = snapshot.data()?['apiKeyValue'];
    if (apiKey != null) {
      return apiKey.toString();
    } else {
      throw Exception('API key not found');
    }
  }

  Future<String> _sendMessage(String message, String apiKey) async {
    setState(() {
      _isTyping = true;
    });

    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions'),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $apiKey',
        },
        body: jsonEncode({
          "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
          "messages": [
            {"role": "system", "content": "You are an AI language assistant."},
            {"role": "user", "content": message}
          ],
        }),
      );

      setState(() {
        _isTyping = false;
      });

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
        if (jsonResponse['choices'] != null &&
            jsonResponse['choices'].isNotEmpty) {
          final aiText =
              jsonResponse['choices'][0]['message']['content'].trim();
          return aiText;
        } else {
          throw Exception('No AI response found in JSON');
        }
      } else {
        print('API Error: ${response.statusCode}');
        throw Exception('Communication with AI model failed');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error occurred: $error');
      throw error;
    }
  }

  void _addMessage(String message) {
    setState(() {
      _messages.add(message);
    });
  }

  Future<void> _sendMessageAndAddMessage(String message) async {
    _textController.clear();
    _messageSent = true;

    // Fetch the API key only when needed, right before sending the message
    final apiKey = await _fetchApiKey();

    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      final userDoc =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid);
      final userDocSnapshot = await userDoc.get();
      if (userDocSnapshot.exists) {
        int currentMessagesSent =
            userDocSnapshot.data()?['AiMessagesSent'] ?? 0;

        if (currentMessagesSent >= 5) {
          // Show the popup if the user has sent 3 or more messages
          _showCodePopup();
          return; // Prevent sending the message
        }

        currentMessagesSent++; // Increment the value
        await userDoc.update({'AiMessagesSent': currentMessagesSent});
      }
    }

    _addMessage('Du: $message');

    if (!_firstMessageSent) {
      setState(() {
        _firstMessageSent = true; // Mark the first message as sent
      });
    }

    if (EnglishQuestionChecker().isEnglishQuestion(message)) {
      try {
        String aiResponse = await _sendMessage(
            message, apiKey); // Pass the apiKey to _sendMessage
        Map<String, dynamic> jsonResponse = json.decode(aiResponse);
        String aiText = jsonResponse['choices'][0]['message']['content'].trim();
        _addMessage('Verby: $aiText');
      } catch (e) {
        _addMessage(
            'Verby: Tut mir leid, ein Fehler ist aufgetreten. Details: $e');
      }
    } else {
      _addMessage(
          'Verby: Entschuldige, jedoch bin ich ausschließlich für gemeinsames Englischlernen hier.');
    }
    _scrollController.animateTo(
      _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    );
  }
```

(Only a part of the code...)

I studied the OpenAI Documentation....

Comment: Maybe `response.body` is not a valid JSON encoded string. What is the exact content of it if you print out with `print(response.body);`?